# Letting $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, must $A$ either be the empty set, or a complement/countable union of a set/sets from $\mathcal{A}$?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of subsets of a set $X$, and $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$, I think $A$ must either be the empty set, or a complement of a set from $\mathcal{A}$, or a countable union of sets from $\mathcal{A}$, since if not, then we could remove $A$ from $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and still have a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$, so $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ could not have been the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$, a contradiction.

Comment: No, this is not true. $A$ could be the complement of a countable union of sets, or a countable union of complements of a countable union of sets, and so forth. Take a look at the Borel hierarchy, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy